# use git to backup folder c:\myfolder to d:\mybackupfolder\ without changing anything in c:\myfolder

Tags: git

I want to use git as a backup tool, and I don't want to change anything in my `c:\myfolder\`  directory, I don't want to create git files inside that. I want to use `d:\mybackupfolder\` for git files. and i want to be able to whenever I run git bash from `d:\mybackupfolder\`in windows explorer, easily just use git command:

```
git commit -a -m "my comment"
```

without setting environmental variables for git.
Is there any solution to make it automatic for git to know where working tree is located whenever I run git bash from my `d:\mybackupfolder\` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change location of the repository worktree:

1. Create an empty repository in d:\mybackupfolder
2. Execute for d:\mybackupfolder repository:

   `git config --local --add core.worktree c:/myfolder/`